# Creating platform specific code in Xamarin?

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin

So I want to implement a twitter login into my Xamarin App, but if I follow the tutorial, the Portable App will not let me do this function:

```
var ui = auth.GetUI(this);
```

when auth is this:

```
var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
  "DynVhdIjJDXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "REvU5dCUQI4MvjV6aWwXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
  new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
  new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
  new Uri("http://twitter.com"));
```

So I need to add it into the Android Project, but how do I show the button from there?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Are you using the RestSharp OAuth1Authenticator?

Comment: Portable app cannot handle UI code.  You need to use an Interface in your portable class project and an implementation class in your android project

Comment: @MalteGoetz yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `OAuth1Authenticator` and `GetUI()` I assume you use Xamarin.Auth.

Xamarin.Auth supports Xamarin.Forms with 2 implementations for `GetUI()`, so called Presenters (actually Dependency Service/Injection) and CustomRenderers. Presenters are more tested (thus more evidence of stabilty), but you can check the code in the repo.

Samples how to use Xamarin.Auth with the Xamarin.Forms:

https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms/Evolve16Labs

NOTE: this repo contains extracted samples from the main Xamarin.Auth repo, so the handling is easier and samples are updated more often.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating platform specific code in Xamarin?

You can use `DependencyService` to implement this function. Here is the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Overview) and [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingDependencyService/). The document explain that :

> DependencyService allows apps to call into platform-specific functionality from shared code. This functionality enables Xamarin.Forms apps to do anything that a native app can do.

Create a `ILogin` interface in PCL :

```
public interface ILogin
{
    void GetUI();
}
```

Implement the interface in Xamarin.Android :

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(TwitterLogin))]
namespace TwitterDemo.Droid
{
  public class TwitterLogin : ILogin
  {

     public TwitterLogin()
     {
     }

     public void GetUI()
     {
        var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator("DynVhdIjJDXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "REvU5dCUQI4MvjV6aWwXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
             new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
             new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
             new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
             new Uri("http://twitter.com"));

        Intent intent = auth.GetUI(Android.App.Application.Context);

        Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
     }

  }
}
```

Use it in Xamarin.Forms:

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ILogin>();
      DependencyService.Get<ILogin>().GetUI();
 }
```